# How to pass a variable to sed

Tags: sed

I want to delete words into a line.  For example:

```
I want to delete one word in this line
```

And I want to delete 'one' to obtain:

```
I want to delete  word in this line
```

By passing the word through a variable. So far I have got:

```
WORD=one ; sed -n 's/"$WORD"//g' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

But, it doesn't do anything.  Why not?  And how can I make it work?

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, only inside double quotes. Double quotes inside single quotes don't have any special effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WORD=one ; sed -e "s/$WORD//g" file.txt > newfile.txt
```

the key moment is variable expansion. You have to be careful though because shell variable expansion may be sometimes not what you want. In hard cases you have to do something like this:

```
EXPANDVAR=one; NOEXPANDVAR=another; sed -e 's/'"$EXPANDVAR"'$NOEXPANDVAR//g' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

In this case sed will replace (remove) pattern one$NOEXPANDVAR , literally.

Comment: wow thanks, indeed it was a hard one, thanks for resolving it !